# FrameHeight under 1 in VStack not accurate

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14

I try to have a small divider between my items in a VStack. But when I add a Color-Line with a frame height of 0.5, the line height is not accurate. At some lines it is a little bit smaller than the other lines and at some lines the divider is fuzzy.

I also tried to use Divider() instead of Color.frame, but it looks same. It seems to be better when I use a frame height of 1, but that's too big for me for a divider.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1CZV.png)

This is my code:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(0...10, id: \.self) { i in
                Color.gray.frame(height: 0.5)
                Text("\(i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what's the problem? Or how I could solve it? Or is it a bug in SwiftUI?

I'm using the current Beta 5 version of iOS 14.

Comment: I think it is just scale effect on Simulator/Preview. Did you try real device?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it looks same on real device

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.frame(height: 1 / UIScreen.main.scale)
```